# How to change CSS classes according to time received by API

Tags: css, reactjs, classname

I'm building a weather app in React and so far so good. The problem is now I want to have a "lightmode" and "darkmode" which should be CSS classes that change according to sunrise/sunset times received by an API. When I did it in vanilla JS I used a function that converted the timestamps into hours and compared the current hour to sunrise/sunset and then decided which class to present, like so

```
function getMode(response) {
  let today = response.data.dt;
  let timezone = response.data.timezone;
  let difference = today + timezone - 3600;
  let hours = timeConverter(difference);
  let mode = document.getElementById("app");
  let sunrise = response.data.sys.sunrise;
  let difference2 = sunrise + timezone - 3600;
  let currentSunrise = timeConverter(difference2);
  let sunset = response.data.sys.sunset;
  let difference3 = sunset + timezone - 3600;
  let currentSunset = timeConverter(difference3) - 1;
  if (hours > currentSunset) {
    mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
  }
  else if (hours < currentSunrise) {
    mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
  } else {
    mode.classList.remove("darkmode").add("lightmode");
  }
}

axios.get(apiUrl).then(getMode)
```

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="lightmode">
```

The CSS then looked like this

```
.lightmode h1 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  color: #06384d;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.lightmode {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a1c4fd 0%, #c2e9fb 100%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #096386;
}

#app {
  margin: 10px 400px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

(...)

.darkmode h1 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.darkmode {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #096386;
}
```

And that worked fine. Now in React (novice here) I don't know how to approach the problem. I've been reading about dynamically changing CSS classes in React with state but I can't figure out how to incorporate that with the API response. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store className in state and change it in your function.

```
class Demo extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      stClass: "lightmode"

    }
 }
 state = {
    stClass: "lightmode"
 }

 componentDidMount = () => {
    [call your function here and change the state of stClass]  
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div className={`${this.state.stClass}`}>
       [your code here]
     </div>
    )
 }

}
```

Comment: I used a variation of your solution to fit my code better (I already have a ```componentDidMount``` which means I can't call it by axios, it won't know which one to call) and it's working fine! Thank you!

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The key part of dynamically changing CSS classes in React would be:

```
<div className={`App ${this.state.displayMode}`}>
```

The class name of the container will be updated anytime the state for displayMode is changed and in this example, appended to the class `App`, resulting in `App darkmode` and rendered as such.

```
<div class="App darkmode">
```

---

**Sample code / use case:**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    displayMode: "lightmode"
  };

  getMode = response => {
    let _displayMode;
    // Logic for determining the mode
    return _displayMode;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Make API call here and run your logic to determine the mode
    axios.get(apiUrl).then(getMode).then(displayMode => {
    // As a callback to your function, set the state for displayMode
      this.setState({
        displayMode: displayMode
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`App ${this.state.displayMode}`}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```